# Loading a non-base R dataset in a shiny application

Tags: r, shiny

I have an app which is meant to render a table of one of two possible datasets: either `mtcars`, which comes with base R's `datasets` package, or `BostonHousing` which comes with the `mlbench` package. For some reason I can't get this to run properly. Can anyone suggest a fix?

```
library(shiny)
library(mlbench)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("select", "Select", 
              choices = c("mtcars", "BostonHousing"),
              selected = "mtcars"),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  dat <- reactive(data(input$select))
  output$table <- renderTable({
    dat()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Edit: for clarification, the data frame must be stored in `dat`. The renderTable component is there only to confirm that it loaded successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my take on it:

```
library(shiny)
library(mlbench)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("select", "Select", 
              choices = c("mtcars", "BostonHousing"),
              selected = "mtcars"),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  dat <- reactive({
    data(input$select)
    get(input$select)
  })
  output$table <- renderTable({
    dat()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

What I've noted:

- you use `renderDataTable` for a `tableOutput`, this does not work, either use `renderTable`/`tableOutput` or use `datatable` (best with the `DT` package)
- `data("BostonHousing")` directly loads the object `BostonHousing` into the environment, whereas `data("mtcars")` only loads a promise, therefore I've added the `get(input$select)` to make it work for `mtcars`

Comment: Thanks Starja. I'm still getting the following error: object 'BostonHousing' not found. I'm guessing your solution worked for you? If so, might be a problem with my RStudio or R base files getting messed up?

Comment: Just tried this on my work computer and still getting the BostonHousing not found error message, so actually don't think it's an issue with RStudio

Comment: Yes, works for me with `R` 4.0.2, `shiny` 1.5.0 and `mlbench` 2.1-1 on Windows. Just to be sure: have you made sure that `mlbench` is loaded?

Comment: I think I understand the issue is; if I run data(BostonHousing) from within RStudio before running the app, then the dataset loads as it is loaded into the working environment. If you try to run the code from a new session without first running data(BostonHousing), then it won't run as the object hasn't been loaded into the environment.

Comment: You're right, sorry I missed that during development of the answer. It seems `data` doesn't evaluate `input$select` but takes it as a string literal to read the dataset; maybe I can find a solution for this

Comment: All good. I figured out an alternate way to do it, or more accurately, some fellow users helped me figure out an alternate way to do it :)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64744192/using-map-with-a-vector-of-data-table-names-and-utilsdata?noredirect=1#comment114476872_64744192

Answer (score 1):

```
library(shiny)
library(mlbench)
library(DT)



ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("select", "Select", 
              choices = c("mtcars","BostonHousing"),
              selected = "mtcars"),
     DT::dataTableOutput("table")

)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

        data(BostonHousing)
        output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
  
            DT::datatable(get(input$select))   
    })

}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks Maydin - I appreciate the response but doesn't fully work for my use case. I need the data frame to be stored in 'dat', and I can't hardcode in loading BostonHousing.